# how to work in two working directories in git?

Tags: git

I work in two working directories in different machines. To manage two directories I made bare repository in "my com". If I do not care each time two directories are different and bare repository would sync one of them. Then sometimes "git push" fails. At the moment I am the only one who uses two working directories.

1. Case 1: there is no collision in the files. Then it might be that
   "git pull" then "git push" can work. Is this right?
2. Case 2: if the same files are modified differently in both directories, how can I deal with this problem?
3. is it better to use branch? then it looks difficult also to merge.

still git is not so easy to me.

Comment: Your question is really difficult to understand and seems too vague... but you should probably learn about what is “merging” in git (and also how to ask questions on stackoverflow ;) Regarding git merge there are tons of resources on the internet.

Comment: If you're saying that you're changing files in the working folder of the remote you push against, then don't do that. Set up a bare repository and push against that, then pull from that into a readonly copy on your production server or whatever. Other than that, your question is really vague, can you explain more about what you're trying to accomplish here?

Comment: this is not about merge. I am asking about how to manage two working directories and remote repository.

Answer (score 1):

To start off: I would suggest going through some tutorials on how git works and how to manage remotes. The official Git documentation is a good starting place.

To give an answer:

Keeping both repositories in sync should be very simple.

For example:

If you are working on your office pc and have made some changes:

1. Commit those changes
2. Do a `git pull` pointing to your "local" PC's
   remote

If you are working on your local pc and have made some changes:

1. Commit those changes
2. Do a `git pull` pointing to your "server" PC's
   remote

In any case there is no need to push stuff anywhere since you are the only one working on these files.

Regarding conflicts: If you have changed the same file on both sides, you should know which version you want to keep and use a standard merge conflict resolution procedure.